# Django on AWS EC2 - Do I need anything installed on my local computer?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My host OS is Windows 8. I downloaded VMWare Player and did all my Django stuff using Lubuntu through VMware Player. Now, my Django project is complete and I want to make it accessible through the internet. I bought a domain using NameCheap. I created an AWS free tier account and launched an EC2 instance (the instance's OS is Ubuntu). Now I'm following this tutorial on how to use AWS Elastic Beanstalk to deploy my Django app.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html

In the tutorial, step 1 is to Set Up Your Git Repository. In step 1, it says to down EB command line tooks, GIT, Ruby and Python on my local computer. Step 2 is to set up my local python environment (download virtualenv, django, mysql-python etc.). My question is, do I really download all this stuff from step 1 and 2 on my host OS (windows 8) or do I install it on my Lubuntu VM after running VMWare Player or do I install it on my AWS instance?

Answer (score 2):

In the example which you have pointed from AWS's Documentation - [Deploying a Django Application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html); you would be configuring the Elasticbeanstalk from local computer - it is illustrated in the Step 3. The general activities which you be performing from your local machine are git repo initializing, start / stop beanstalk etc.

You may reuse your VMware virtual machine to use that the local machine as specified in the documentation.

Comment: @Naveem hm okay so to clarify, I can use my VMware Player virtual machine as the 'local computer'? Because I can't seem to find where it says that anywhere in the documentation which I linked to.

Comment: Even I am not sure whether that will; you may give it a shot at that. As long as you are able to connect to your internet from your VMware Instance, I guess you should be able do that.